# sqlite: select all columns where one filed has max value over all columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, max

I have a table like this:

```
id int, col1 int, ...
```

Different rows can have col1 of same value.
Now I want to gather all rows where col1 has a the maximum value.
e.g. this table values

```
1 4
2 3
3 4
```

The query shall give my row 1 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subquery:

```
SELECT id, col1
FROM tab
WHERE col1 = (SELECT MAX(col1) FROM tab);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/da946/6/0)**</kbd>